# When configuring JwtBearer or OpenIDConnect, Bearer error="invalid_token", c# .net 7

Tags: c#, rest, openid-connect, .net-7.0

Could use a hand getting JwtBearer or OpenIdConnect working with a webapi.

Generally when configuring an app I look for OpenIdConnect settings and configure as expected.  This works and I've got single signon working with several apps.  I believe this should eliminate keycloak as a suspect variable.

With the code below I was getting a 302 and after much searching added in the `options.Events` which led to the current 401 error:

```
    < HTTP/2 401
    < date: Sun, 26 Feb 2023 16:29:54 GMT
    < content-length: 0
    < www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"
    < strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

However, I can take the bearer token being used and copy it out to jwt.io and it shows as valid.  Not sure why the webapi is struggling here.

When I test, I'm using the swagger, clicking on the authentication and copying in 'Bearer ' then Executing a method which has the '[Authorize]'.

After increasing log level I'm now also seeing:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No SecurityTokenValidator available for token.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
```

I've updated packages.  Here's the code snippet:

Startup.cs

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetSection("appSettings")["auth0Domain"] + "/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.Audience = Configuration.GetSection("appSettings")["auth0Audience"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
        //add more configs
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                context.Token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;


    // Configure Cors
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                //builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                //                    "http://www.contoso.com");
            });
    });
```

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Service service)
        {
            Globals.service = service;
            service.Start();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            // Allow cross-site calls
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseWebSockets();

            // Handle incoming webrequests in order to start WebSockets
            app.Use(async (context, next) => { await Globals.service.tm.HandleWebRequest(context, next); });
        }
```

Comment: can you add the app,UseXXXX(); part of the program.cs class as well?

Comment: How do you pass the token to the application? Can you add that to the question?
Can you also post a sample access token to your question? Also, add how you  configured Authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to add the options.Events part, if you pass the token via the usual **Authorization: bearer** header.

I recently blogged about troubleshooting JwtBearer problems [here](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/) and I hope that can give you some ideas. See my comments for additional things to add to your question.

Comment: I removed the options.Events part and everything started working.

Very much appreciated your article troubleshooting JwtBearer, I'm sure that will be a game changer for many for several years to come.